# Handle on scroll up and scroll down Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Use the following code to change my element border radius on scroll down:

```
var scrollT = 0;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var val = (document.getElementById("bx").style.borderRadius).replace("%", "");
    if (st > scrollT ) {
        if (val <= 50) {
            val -= 1;
            val += "%";
            document.getElementById("bx").style.borderRadius = val;
        }
    }

    scrollT = st;     
});
```

How I can handle scroll top for change element border radius to `50%`?

Comment: A bit offtopic, but why don't you write $("#bx") when you already have jQuery?

Comment: i wrote this, but returned undefined. i had to:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a trick you can use, **you just have to check the current scrollTop position vs the previous scrollTop**

Once you got that either you are scrolling up or down, you can do whatever you want accordingly.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       $("#atul").text("scrolling Down now");
   } else {
      $("#atul").text("scrolling Up now");
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
body{height: 1500px;}

#atul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="atul">Just Scroll to check</p>
```